# Scala: call a user define function like a member function

Tags: scala

I'm using a collection of type `Seq[T]`, and I wrote a transformation function for it

```
foo(a: Seq[T): Seq[T] = ...
```

I want to call `foo` like this

```
val a: Seq[T] = ...
a.foo
```

instead of

```
foo(a)
```

Is this possible?

I would later want foo to be generic, i.e. `foo[T](a: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = ...`

Comment: Yes, take a look at [implicit classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [implicit classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) in Scala.
Something like this:

```
object Helpers {
  implicit class SeqWrap[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
    def foo: Unit = {
      println("BLA")
    }
  }
}

import Helpers._

Seq(1,2).foo // prints "BLA"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "pimp" `Seq[T]` using implicit class like:

```
implicit class SeqEx[T](val seq: Seq[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def foo: Seq[T] = ...
}
```

See: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-2.10-implicit-class-example

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible if you implement extension method via implicit conversion or implicit class:

```
object Main {
  def foo[T](a: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = ???

  implicit class SeqWithFoo[T](a: Seq[T]) {
    def foo = Main.foo(a)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    trait T
    val a: Seq[T] = ???
    a.foo
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create implicit method that translates `Seq` to `RichSeq` which will have extra method you want.

```
class RichSeqSpecs extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("richSeq") {

    class RichSeq[T] (val seq: Seq[T]) {
      def foo = "do something"
    }

    implicit def seqToRichSeq[T](seq: Seq[T]) = new RichSeq[T](seq)

    Seq(1, 2, 3).foo shouldBe "do something"
    Seq("hi", "how are you").foo shouldBe "do something"

  }
}
```

OrElse, you don't even have to create a separate implicit method, you can just tell the `RichSeq` class to be implicit,

```
class TypeSpecs extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("richSeq") {

    implicit class RichSeq[T] (val seq: Seq[T]) {
      def foo = "do something"
    }

    Seq(1, 2, 3).foo shouldBe "do something"
    Seq("hi", "how are you").foo shouldBe "do something"

  }
}
```